# Java UUID or QueryBuilder uuid

Tags: java, cassandra

I'm using `Datastax` Java driver to perform basic insert statement in Cassandra database. My primary key column is `uuid` type. From what I see in official documentation, recommended way to call `uuid()` function in Cassandra is to use [QueryBuilder#uuid()](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/querybuilder/QueryBuilder.html#uuid--) method. However, is it safe to use java util's `UUID.randomUUID()` too, since my types are colliding (QueryBuilder.uuid() returns `Object` while `UUID.randomUUID()` returns `UUID`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UUID.randomUUID() creates type-4 UUID and it is safe to use.

Infact, datastax UUID utility class [com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/UUIDs.html#random--) has a method named random(), which is just a convenience for UUID.randomUUID()

Comment: What if you need to store existing UUID? Like a cookie ?

Comment: @lisak UUID is serializable. You can use libraries like jackson to serialize/de-serialize.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the generated UUID for ordering (clustering key), please use `QueryBuilder#uuid()`. This is because Cassandra has a different  [implementation](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/d9083a9c2946dfc9d82e9784369abc3387c445a7/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/utils/UUIDGen.java). The Java UUID ordering is different.

If you are using it as any other key, it doesn't matter.

Hope it helps!